# Django: Is APPEND_SLASH set to True even if not in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, web

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

If I type `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` in my browser (Firefox) I get redirected to `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` (with slash at the end).

To be honest, I am confused why that is. Because in my `settings.py`there is no

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
```

However, the Django docs say:

> APPEND_SLASH
>
> Default: True
>
> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the
>   patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP
>   redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that
>   the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be
>   lost.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash

Is it that APPEND_SLASH is True by default even if it's not in `settings.py`? And that you should only put it in this file if you want to set it to False?
Or what's the reason for that behaviour?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the default is `True`, so if you don't provide it in your settings file it will be `True`.

Any setting that is not defined in your settings file will use the default value, which is provided in [`django.conf.global_settings`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py#L229).

Answer (score 2):

In your settings.py in the installed apps you might notice you have `CommonMiddleware`

This middleware takes care of adding '/' to the end of URLs.

Snippet from the documentation:

> class CommonMiddleware[source]
>
> Adds a few conveniences for perfectionists:
>
> Forbids access to user agents in the DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS setting, which should be a list of compiled regular expression objects.
>
> Performs URL rewriting based on the APPEND_SLASH and PREPEND_WWWsettings.
>
> If APPEND_SLASH is True and the initial URL doesn’t end with a slash, and it is not found in the URLconf, then a new URL is formed by appending a slash at the end. If this new URL is found in the URLconf, then Django redirects the request to this new URL. Otherwise, the initial URL is processed as usual.
>
> For example, foo.com/bar will be redirected to foo.com/bar/ if you don’t have a valid URL pattern for foo.com/bar but do have a valid pattern for foo.com/bar/.

You can read more here : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/